# Remove all HTML tags inside of selection in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rangy

I have a `<div />` which is `contenteditable` and can contain several types of HTML elements such as `<span />`, `<a />`, `<b />`, `<u />` and so on.

Now when I select text in my `contenteditable` I would like to have a button that removes all the styles within the selection.

**Example 1:**

The Selection:

```
Hello <b>there</b>. I am <u>a selection</u>
```

would become:

```
Hello there. I am a selection
```

**Example 2:**

The Selection:

```
<a href="#">I am a link</a>
```

would become:

```
I am a link
```

You get the idea...

I have found this helpful function https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997896/1503476 which replaces the current selection with custom text. But I just cannot get the content of the selection first and strip the tags out before replacing it. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would do this is to iterate over the nodes within the selection and remove inline nodes (maybe leaving `<br>` elements alone). Here's an example, using my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library for convenience. It works in all major browsers (including IE 6) but is not quite perfect: for example, it does not split partially selected formatting elements, meaning that a partially selected formatting element is completely removed rather than just the selected portion. To fix this would be more tricky.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fQCZT/4/

Code:

```
var getComputedDisplay = (typeof window.getComputedStyle != "undefined") ?
    function(el) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(el, null).display;
    } :
    function(el) {
        return el.currentStyle.display;
    };

function replaceWithOwnChildren(el) {
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    while (el.hasChildNodes()) {
        parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
    }
    parent.removeChild(el);
}


function removeSelectionFormatting() {
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();

    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        for (var i = 0, range; i < sel.rangeCount; ++i) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(i);

            // Split partially selected nodes 
            range.splitBoundaries();

            // Get formatting elements. For this example, we'll count any
            // element with display: inline, except <br>s.
            var formattingEls = range.getNodes([1], function(el) {
                return el.tagName != "BR" && getComputedDisplay(el) == "inline";
            });

            // Remove the formatting elements
            for (var i = 0, el; el = formattingEls[i++]; ) {
                replaceWithOwnChildren(el);
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: man i also got link of RANGY plugin but i can't figure out the solution but you did thumbs up :)

Comment: In Firefox, you can select multiple pieces of text by keeping the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed while selecting. Your script removes the formatting only from the 1<sup>st</sup> selection.

Comment: @user2428118: That's true, but no other browser supports that or is likely to, and the [current spec](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#selections) only talks about a single selection range. Therefore a while ago I stopped bothering to handle the multiple range case in Stack Overflow answers; you're the first to complain. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fQCZT/2/

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>
        Here is some <b>formatted text</b>. Please select some and watch the formatting
        <i>magically disappear</i>.
        <br>
        Look, some more <u>formatted</u> content.
    </p>
    <p>And <i>another</i> paragraph of it</p>
</div>
<button onmousedown="removeSelectionFormatting()">Change</button>​
```

It is duplicate of one of the above answers but with a button to change text!

Comment: I don't want to replace the whole surrounding `div`. I'm working on a selection inside of the `contenteditable` `div`...

Comment: you want to remove tags of selected text? i edit my answer if yes!

Comment: yes, I want to remove the tags that are inside of the selection.

Comment: give me some time i am trying to make!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggested function, I came up with this neat little script after a little bit of experimenting in the console. *Didn't test this for cross browser compatibility though*!

```
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.cloneContents().childNodes[0]; // This is your selected text.
```

Now, you can strip HTML tags from your selectedText and replace it using the function you already provided in your question.

For example, you could use `strip_tags()` from [the php.js project](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: That doesn't work. I cannot apply the `strip_tags` function to `selectedText`. It will return `TypeError: input.replace is not a function`

Comment: Maybe the strip_tags function is not what you seek and you could combine my answer with, for example, @gulty's answer.

I assumed you already had a solution to replace the string, using the answer in the link you provided: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3997896/1503476

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tnyWD/

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    Hello <b>there </b><a href="#">I am a link</a>
</div>
<button class="remove">Remove HTML</button>​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.fn.stripTags = function() { return this.replaceWith(this.html().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '') ); };
$('.remove').click(function(){
    $('.test').stripTags();
});
});​
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm working on a selection in a `contenteditable` div. So the stripTags I need to apply only to the selection!