# Replace Highlighted Text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i am not able to replace the highlighted text..here is the code of my sample which just does highlighting:

CSS:

```
.highlight
{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
function highlight(text)
{
   var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
    var innerHTML1 = inputText.innerHTML;
    var index = innerHTML1.indexOf(text);
    if ( index >= 0 )
    { 
        innerHTML1 = innerHTML1.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML1.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML1.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML1; 

    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="highlight('fox')">Highlight</button>


<div id="inputText">
The fox went over the fence
</div>
```

Let me know the code for replacing the highlighted text..

While googling, i have got one link..but it is creating a new node..here is the link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997659/replace-selected-text-in-contenteditable-div?rq=1`

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sN9sA/ What would you like to replace the highlighted text with? Here's one that replaces the selected text with the second parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/sN9sA/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to highlight *and* replace, you only have to update a single line.

The second line of this snippet *(line breaks for convenience)* is the highlighted text. In your original snippet you use the the same part of the text your search matched. Replace it with something else and voilà:

```
innerHTML1 = innerHTML1.substring(0, index)
             + "<span class='highlight'>" + "Fynn the fox" + "</span>" 
             + innerHTML1.substring(index + text.length);
```

And the matching [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN9sA/2/).

Or, a [combination](http://jsfiddle.net/sN9sA/3/), which could look like this:

```
innerHTML1 = innerHTML1.substring(0, index)
             + "<span class='highlight'> [Match: " + innerHTML1.substring(index, index + text.length)
             + "]</span>" + innerHTML1.substring(index + text.length);
```