# Get highlighted text as a node in javascript

Tags: javascript

Working on a bit of javascript code; I'm wanting to alter the text when highlighted. The closest I've found currently is this: [Get The Highlighted Selected Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text). The problem with that solution though is it just gets the text that's highlighted as a string, but it's as a string. So I have the text, but I can't edit it like a node, doing innerHTML, change font, etc. It's just a string. I've got a solution that "works"™, but what is, is taking that string, and then searching for it. The problem is, if for example I highlight the string "the" in this post, I'd get a whole bunch of answers and no way to differentiate between them.

Is there a way to get selected text as a node?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get the html element that the selected text is in so that you can apply something to it?

Comment: Kind of. Getting the element it's in might include more than I want. So if I was going for a highlighted "the" in this sentence, I'd get the whole sentence, not just the the.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for the selection (`window.getSelection();`)and get its range to have the right position of the selected text. Then you can apply styles by span-wrapping. 
Take a look at

http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/bZb7V/

Answer (score 1):

You can get an idea of how its done from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3997896/5267669

Basically you get the selected text with the `document.getSelection` method, you delete it and in its place you insert your own content.

For example replace your selection with an H1 tag containing the text `Added with js`

```
sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
   range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
   range.deleteContents();
   var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
   h1.textContent = 'Added with js';
   range.insertNode(h1);
}
```

You can select anything on this page, paste this code to the console and the selection will be replaced with an h1 tag