# Insert HTML at caret in a contenteditable div in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable

How can we use React to add a span tag to the last place where the cursor is in a div whose contentEditable property is already set to true(**package react-contenteditable**)? This div contains only plain text and a span tag. The span tag should be treated as a single character, and nothing else should be created within it. A button should be used to insert a new span at the last point where the cursor was.

**Attention** : The user should not be able to add anything in the selected text again.

[codesandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-field-l42xxt?file=/src/App.tsx)

like this :

[image: svg]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace selected text in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997659/replace-selected-text-in-contenteditable-div)